# Type mismatch - (Int, Vector) instead of Vector

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to `parallelize` my dataset however, a `type mismatch` error occurs once I try to instantiate a `RowMatrix` using the repartitioned data.

Here's is the code for reading and repartitioning the data:

```
val data = sc.textFile("data.txt.gz").flatMap(r => r.split(' ') match {
  case Array(doc, word, count) => Some((doc.toInt, (word.toInt - 1, count.toDouble)))
  case _ => None
}).groupByKey().mapValues(a => Vectors.sparse(vocab_size, a.toSeq))

val repartitioned = sc.parallelize(Seq(data), 10)
```

Now I am not quite sure how to construct a `RowMatrix` since

```
val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(repartitioned)
```

gives the following error:

```
Main.scala:59: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
        val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(repartitioned)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parallelize is for creating and RDD from a Seq of local values, you already have an RDD.  Trying to call parallelize on it doesn't work because you are trying to put an rdd into an rdd.  If you want to repartition your data use the repartition method.  ie. `data.repartition(10)`

When you call mapValues, it only applies to operation to the values of your pairs, but the resulting RDD is still an RDD[(Key,Value)].  If you wish to discard the keys then just use map instead of mapValues.